# Need help getting this procedure iterativ

Tags: scheme

```
(define (length2 item)
   (if (null? item)
     0
  (+ 1 (length2 (cdr item)))))
```

This is the recursive version I made, but I'm really struggling trying to make it iterativ. I have a fairly good understanding on the difference between the two. In recursive it just adds +1 and when it reaches the end, it adds all the 1's together, while in iterativ it calculates it each step.(Feel free to let me know if I've misunderstood.)

Do any of you have any ideas how to make it iterativ and some tips for me to get a better understanding of it in Scheme?

Sorry if this is a trivial question, but I'm fairly new to this language and functional programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `count` variable to make it iterative and keep track of the length

```
(define (length2 item count)
(if (null? item)
    count
    ((length2 (cdr item) (+ count 1)))))
```

---

**EDIT:**

The way defined above, you will need to call the procedure `length2` with an initial value of `0` for `count`.

If you do not want to do that then you can make an intermediate function to take care of this. It would look something like this

```
(define (actual_length item count)
(if (null? item)
    count
    ((actual_length (cdr item) (+ count 1)))))

(define (length2 item) (length2 item 0))
```

Now, with this you can call the `length2` procedure normally, like

```
(length2 the_list)
```

Comment: But don't you have to give count a number when you call it?
Like this: (length2 '(1 2 3) 0) ?

Comment: The way that is written, yes. Consider renaming the function in the answer to `length2-helper`. Then you can do a `(define (length2 item) (length2-helper item 0))`

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? I don't quite understand